# NoMethodError when attempting to use open_id_authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm currently adding OpenID login support for a Rails 3.0.0 application.

I have already installed `ruby-openid` (the gem) and `open_id_authentication` (the plugin). However, after following the steps required to set up both (from the READMEs), I am still getting this error:

```
undefined method `authenticate_with_open_id'
```

I tried Googling the problem, but most threads seem to date from years ago and remain suspiciously unanswered.

Am I missing something obvious? What is causing this problem? Note that I have had no problems switching to file-based stores in environment.rb, so I am sure that the plugin is correctly installed.

Update: Some unresolved problems of the same nature:

http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=23151

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing a similar error; oddly, I have this working on Rails 3.2 on another branch, and can't figure out the difference; anyhow I found that I got a little further by following suggestions here: [Rails 3.0.9 + open_id_authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446143/rails-3-0-9-open-id-authentication)

That is, adding the line `include OpenIdAuthentication` after `class SessionsController < ApplicationController`:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  include OpenIdAuthentication
```

But now I get a `Completed 401 Unauthorized` in my log, and see a blank page -- just  and  tags. Ugh.

**Update:** Ooh, got further; I followed this post: [open_id_authentication - "OpenIdAuthentication.store is nil. Using in-memory store." problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683611/open-id-authentication-openidauthentication-store-is-nil-using-in-memory-sto)

and as they suggested, "added an initializer named config/initializers/openid.rb with this inside":

```
require 'open_id_authentication' # this was needed, but not described in the referred-to post
OpenIdAuthentication.store = :file
```

I was then directed to the OpenId provider and was able to click "allow", but on returning to my app, I now see:

```
NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
undefined method `encoding' for nil:NilClass
```

Anyhow, finally, I found a restful routes problem and fixed that, and now logging in works!