# Rails: using other login with Enki blogging gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I'm trying to set up a blog with Rails and really like Enki www.Enkiblog.com. However, I'm a bit confused about the authentication system it uses with Open Id. On development, it allows you to bypass authentication, but for production it seems to require you to use an OpenId server
[image]

I'm hoping to incorporate a simpler authentication system with it, but don't know if that's simpler (I'm a noob) or if it's better to try to figure out how to set up an OpenId server (which requires more installation)

I did look at an Open Id server called Masquerade but it totally confused me. I'm not sure if it's something I try to incorporate with Enki (like a Rails Engine) or if it's a totally separate application.

Any thoughts how I can simplify the authentication, or how it can be simplified so that a noob can use it?

This is the enki.yml file that sets up for OpenId authentication in Enki

```
   # Configuration options for your blog - customise to taste
    # This file contains no secret information, so can be stored in source control (unlike database.yml)
    title: My Enki Blog
    url:   http://enkiblog.com
    author:
      name:    Don Alias        # For copyright notice and ATOM feeds
      email:   don@enkiblog.com # Exception emails will go here, and it is used in ATOM feeds
      open_id:                  # These are used to login to the admin area
          - http://enkiblog.com
          - http://secondaryopenid.com

    # Delete the following section if your site will not be acting as an OpenID delegate (http://wiki.openid.net/Delegation)
    # If you're deploying with mongrel, make sure you read http://rhnh.net/2008/04/13/nginx-openid-delegation-and-yadis
    open_id_delegation:
      server:   http://www.myopenid.com/server
      delegate: http://username.myopenid.com
```

This is the create action from admin/sessions controller that does that authentication

```
def create
    return successful_login if allow_login_bypass? && params[:bypass_login]

    if params[:openid_url].blank? && !request.env[Rack::OpenID::RESPONSE]
      flash.now[:error] = "You must provide an OpenID URL"
      render :action => 'new'
    else
      authenticate_with_open_id(params[:openid_url]) do |result, identity_url|
        if result.successful?
          if enki_config.author_open_ids.include?(URI.parse(identity_url))
            return successful_login
          else
            flash.now[:error] = "You are not authorized"
          end
        else
          flash.now[:error] = result.message
        end
        render :action => 'new'
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. I have successfully signed up with myopenid.com, and am pleased with it, and would like to stick with it. I hope a solution is eventually found.

Comment: This solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683611/open-id-authentication-openidauthentication-store-is-nil-using-in-memory-sto

Answer (score 0):

All you need is an open id at google (your profile url) or any of the open id providers at [openid.net](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/). Once you have found your open id url, all you need to do is open *config/enki.yml* and change the open-id value to your open id url. e.g.:

```
open_id:                  # These are used to login to the admin area
    - https://plus.google.com/102381073183096542549
```

Now to login at admin panel, just enter your profile url. It may ask you to login at your open id provider's site like google.com and then ask for permissions for *yourblog.com*. Once granted, you will have the admin access. Nobody else will be able to access admin area since you have restricted it to the open_id in enki.yml

Answer (score -1):

You can actually rip out the OpenID Authentication out of Enki by hacking the code.  I managed to do this (Rails newbie) so it isn't all that difficult.

The only problem with this being that now you are on your own for updating the Enki code... From what I remember there were quite a few changes that had to be made to accomplish this.