# redmine get error like the following

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, redmine

Every thing is working on the production server, but when the initial root page loads than the following message as an error printed in the Apache error.log

```
OpenIdAuthentication.store is nil. Using in-memory store.
```

We have the redmine version 2.3

And that version have the following configurations as below

ruby 1.9.3
rails 3.2.15
mysql2

Any one can help to get resolved that issue.

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683611/open-id-authentication-openidauthentication-store-is-nil-using-in-memory-sto
Take a look to link upper and try to follow instructions in accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, Done from there.